# ListView by using custom list view adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to use list view by using custom list view adapter. My problem is that I am not getting list view at run time in my app.

CourseActivity.java

```
package com.technerdshub.vusocial.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import com.technerdshub.vusocial.DBHelper;
import com.technerdshub.vusocial.Models.Course;
import com.technerdshub.vusocial.Models.StudyProgramModel;
import com.technerdshub.vusocial.Models.User;
import com.technerdshub.vusocial.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CourseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    CourseViewAdapter adapter;
    Course courseObject;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.course_activity);


        List<Course> courseList;
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
        courseList = db.getAllCourses();

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        for (Course c : courseList)
        {
            arrayList.add(c);
        }

        adapter = new CourseViewAdapter(this, arrayList);
        adapter.courseActivity = this;
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        User user = User.getInstance();
        saveUserOnParse(user);

    }

    private void saveUserOnParse(User user) {
        ParseObject parseUser = new ParseObject("UserData");
        parseUser.put("name", user.getName());
        parseUser.put("vuId", user.getVuId());
        parseUser.put("studyProgram", user.getStudyProgram());
        parseUser.put("facebookId", user.getFacebookId());
        parseUser.put("facebookEmail", user.getFacebookEmail());
        parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e==null){
//                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), StudentDashboardActivity.class);
////                    i.putExtra("E-mail", "abc");
//                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else {
                    Toast temp = Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this,"Data is not saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    temp.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 4

        if(requestCode==2)
        {
            courseObject = (Course) data.getExtras().getSerializable("SelectedCourse");

        }

    }
}
```

CourseViewAdapter.java

```
package com.technerdshub.vusocial.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.technerdshub.vusocial.Models.Course;
import com.technerdshub.vusocial.Models.StudyProgramModel;
import com.technerdshub.vusocial.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Saroosh on 7/16/2016.
 */
public class CourseViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected CourseActivity courseActivity;
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Course>worldpopulationlist=null;
    private ArrayList<Course> arraylist;

    public CourseViewAdapter(Context context, List<Course>worldpopulationlist){
        mContext = context;
        this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Course>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView courseCode;
        TextView courseName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Course getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.c_list_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml

            holder.courseName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.course_name);
            holder.courseCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.course_code);
            // holder.duration    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.program_duration);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.courseName.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCourseName());

        holder.courseCode.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCourseCode());

        //holder.duration.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getDuration());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CourseActivity.class);
                // Pass all data ran
                intent.putExtra("SelectedCourse", worldpopulationlist.get(position));
                // Pass all data country
                courseActivity.setResult(2,intent);

                courseActivity.finish();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        worldpopulationlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
        }
        else
        {
            for (Course wp : arraylist)
            {
                if (wp.getCourseName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

course_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".Activities.CourseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        >
    </include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_c" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

c_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course_code"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"

        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/course_code"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"

        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You get any error in logcat? Post?

Comment: When you already have created courselist then why you are creating another list from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for it as you need to return size in adapter getCount method:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arraylist.size();
}

@Override
public Course getItem(int position) {
    return arraylist.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all your `getCount()` returns 0 which means you are telling the `Adapter` that there's nothing in there, try returning `arraylist.size()`

Moreover, why are there two lists in your `Adapter`?

Edit : Nevermind, it's for your filtering I see, then try returning `worldpopulationlist.size()`

Answer (score 1):

Get your **worldpopulationlist** array count

```
public int getCount() {
    return worldpopulationlist.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these methods

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Course getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

Change your class definition

```
public class CourseViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Course>
```

Use only one list (there's an alternative, correct way, to apply filters to an Adapter)

```
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Course> arraylist;

public CourseViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Course> list){
    super(context, 0, list);
    mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = list;
}
```

Your problem was that the getCount method tells the UI how many elements to draw. You must implement that in a BaseAdapter, but an ArrayAdapter does that for you

Answer (score 0):

in your xml`course_activity.xml` you have to initialize ListView

```
  <ListView
  android:id="@+id/listview1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In listView you have to inflate your `c_list_item.xml` layout.

I hope it will work for you.